# Above div overlaps footer div when there are many rows of table

Tags: html, css

I do want the footer div to stay on the bottom of page even if there are no rows on the table,its working find,the footer is at bottom when there is less content,but when there are long content,footer stays on its position, and the table content passes through the footer like a ghost. I dont know what term but see my fiddle and try to scroll down.

```
<style>
#footer{
    position : fixed;
    bottom : 0px;
    width : 100%;
}
</style>
<div>
    <table>
    <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<div><label id = "footer">Footer here</label></div>
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5VANy/)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by like this way:

```
#tblContent{
overflow: auto;
height: 742px;
}

<div id="tblContent">
 <table>
    <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5VANy/4/)

Comment: Nothing change, above div still passes through the footer in your fiddle

Comment: You want to do like if content size increases then footer goes down?

Comment: @Niang in that case it will not feasible solution because your web page will also have maximum size so you need to make fixed height or maxheight table otherwise  how much you will allow to have more size to your table?

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for that, not what i wanted output but thanks. Maybe I will change what i want.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the footer stick to the bottom of your content.  For example, here's a fiddle when there is a lot of content: http://jsfiddle.net/uQ8s2/.  And, here's a fiddle when there are few rows: http://jsfiddle.net/w6JYp/.

HTML:

```
see fiddles
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -40px; 
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

footer {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: teal;
}
```

Comment: Hi, @DRD is this supported by all browser?

Comment: It'll work on all modern browsers and most browsers in general.  `box-sizing` is supported by IE8 and up and in Mozilla I think you still have to use prefix `-moz`.  In browsers that go way back, instead of using box-sizing you can use extra markup: http://jsfiddle.net/A73aT/.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving height to the table's parent div. Below is a jquery script to calculate the height dynamically.

HTML

```
    <div class="container">
        <table>
            <tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr>...
        </table>
    </div>
```

JS

```
    var gutterspace = 20; //Space between the container and the footer
    var cal_height = $(window).height() - ($('#footer').height() + gutterspace);
    $('.container').css('height',cal_height);
```

CSS

```
.container{ overflow:auto; }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/5VANy/5/)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is  http://yui3.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/sticky-footer-with-css/ if you can afford to use `box-sizing` (not supported by all browsers) let me know I shall provide you better solution

Answer (score 0):

Just add background-color: #ffffff in your footer class, like this:

```
#footer{
    position : fixed;
    bottom : 0px;
    width : 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

I have tested this on fiddler.